# With Redux and Typescript, how do I properly type a "mapStateToProps" function to allow for only 2 of 3 arguments to be passed via state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, mapstatetoprops

I'm using React 18 with Redux 8 and Typescript.  I want to create a component that allows the caller to pass in one of the arguments, but the other two arguments are derived from state.  So I created this file ...

```
type OrderItemComponentProps = {
  contact: Contact | undefined;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  orderItem: OrderItem;
}

const OrderItemComponent: React.FC<OrderItemComponentProps> = ({ contact, isAuthenticated, orderItem }) => {
    ...
}

function mapStateToProps(state: RootState, ownProps: OrderItemComponentProps): OrderItemComponentProps {
  return {
    contact: ownProps.contact, // passed as a prop to the container
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated, // derived from Redux state
    orderItem: state.orderItem.orderItem // derived from Redux state
  }
}

export const OrderItemContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(OrderItemComponent)
```

In a separate file, I invoke the above using

```
<OrderItemContainer contact={orderItem.sender} />
```

But this generates the Typescript error

```
Type '{ contact: Contact | undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ contact: Contact | undefined; isAuthenticated: boolean; orderItem: OrderItem; context?: Context<ReactReduxContextValue<any, AnyAction>> | undefined; store?: Store<...> | undefined; }': isAuthenticated, orderItem
```

What is the right way to type my "mapStateToProps" function so properly allow a declaration of this component?

Comment: I think you need to "extend" your props with the return type of `mapStateToProps` so the props it injects are included. However, you are using React function components and trying to use old and outdated Redux. Try using the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks instead of the effectively deprecated `connect` Higher Order Component.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the type definition of `connect` is weird. The most straightforward way to approach this is to split the type definition between what is returned from `mapStateToProps` and parent `props`. Luckily, `ReturnType` allows you to infer the interface of `mapStateToProps`. Then use type casting to force the resulting component to only need the parent props, which is `contact`. It should look something like this

```
type OrderItemComponentProps = {
  contact: Contact | undefined;
}

const OrderItemComponent: React.FC<OrderItemComponentProps & ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> = ({ contact, isAuthenticated, orderItem }) => {
    return null
}

function mapStateToProps(state: RootState) {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated, // derived from Redux state
    orderItem: state.orderItem.orderItem // derived from Redux state
  }
}

export const OrderItemContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(OrderItemComponent) as React.FC<OrderItemComponentProps>
```